# Invalid constraint expression error in Pyomo

Tags: python, pyomo

I am using the pyomo library to solve a Traveling Salesman Problem (TSP), but there is an error. The main part of the model is as follows:

```
model.set_I = range(lendist, 1) # The set related to the distance matrix
model.set_J = range(nStops, 1) # nStop is the number of cities and set_J is the related set.
model.trips = Var(model.set_I, domain=NonNegativeReals, bounds=(0, 1)) # trips is the decision variable

def obj_expression(model): # Objective function
    return sum(model.dist[i]*model.trips[i] for i in model.set_I)
model.OBJ = Objective(rule=obj_expression)

# Constraint 1:
def constraint_1(model):
    return sum(model.trips[i] for i in model.set_I) == nStops
model.constraint_1 = Constraint(rule=constraint_1)

# Constraint 2:
def constraint_2(model, j):
    return sum(model.trips[whichIdxs[i, j]] for i in model.set_I) == 2
model.constraint_2 = Constraint(model.set_J, rule=constraint_2)
```

The resulting error is as follows:

ERROR: Constructing component 'constraint_1' from data=None failed:

```
ValueError: Invalid constraint expression. The constraint expression resolved to a trivial Boolean (False) instead of a Pyomo object. Please modify your rule to return Constraint. Infeasible instead of False.
```

ValueError: Invalid constraint expression. The constraint expression resolved to a trivial Boolean (False) instead of a Pyomo object. Please modify your rule to return Constraint. Infeasible instead of False.

Error thrown for Constraint constraint_1

Constraint 1 has only index i, and the sum is over it. Therefore, there is no index after the rule definition. Is the problem here? In fact, a similar situation is valid for the objective function, but there is no error about this.

Answer (score 2):

What is the value of `lendist`?

It looks like the `model.set_I` is empty (which will happen if `lendist>=1`).  When Python sums over an empty iterable it returns the integer constant `0`.  Assuming that you have `nStops != 0` , then the expression is evaluated by Python in the `constraint_1` function, causing it to return `False` (and not a Pyomo expression object).  As `False` is not a valid Pyomo expression (and is trivially infeasible), Pyomo raises the error.

Remember that when you pass two arguments to the Python `range()` function, the arguments specify the starting and ending values: `range(start, end)` only returns the integers starting at `start` up to, *but and not including* `end`.